# Universal forwarder is not able to communicate with remote Splunk Indexer

Tags: splunk

I am trying to push my Activemq logs to a remote system Splunk Indexer using Universal forwarder however its not working. On my local system I see the logs as below:

> 06-13-2012 20:29:38.841 +0530 WARN  DeploymentClient - Unable to send
>   handshake message to deployment server. Error status is: not_connected
>   06-13-2012 20:29:40.741 +0530 WARN  TcpOutputProc - Raw connection to
>   ip=ip.address:9997 timed out

Local System OS - Windows-7
Remote system OS - Windows NT 2003

Can anyone help me out to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the deployment server usually runs on port 8089 not 9997, which is typical used for forwarding data.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Windows firewall disable port connection.

You can try adding exception for tcp port 9997 ( if you use this port for receiving data in Splunk server) in advanced firewall setting.